# How can I make a scrolling game using Cocos2D without a tile map?

Tags: iphone, c++, cocos2d-iphone, scroll

I want to move the background when I tilt the iPhone so it will look like it is moving your character. So if I tilt it forward, my background will go backwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a CCParallaxNode.

Here is a good article / blog, about using CCParallaxNode in a 2d scrolling game. In this person's example, they are moving the background on every frame, but you could modify it to only move when tilting the iphone by using the UIAcceleration delegate.

Here is the link: [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3611/how-to-make-a-space-shooter-iphone-game)

Answer (score 2):

In terms of how to handle accelerometer input: In the init method of your layer, add:

`self.isAccelerometerEnabled = YES;`

Then, implement the method:

```
-(void) accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration
```

You can get the accelerometer values by doing

```
accX = acceleration.x; //etc...
```

Now in terms of the animation, there's a couple ways to do it. One way you could do it is just make a large image, add it to a layer, and then adjust its position based on accelerometer input. However, this is very memory inefficient and not ideal. Why are you so opposed to using tile maps? They are quite useful for what you have in mind. A good resource for an introduction to them is at: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1163/how-to-make-a-tile-based-game-with-cocos2d